# What does a single ampersand mean in a PHP conditional statement?

Tags: php, if-statement, ampersand

The following code uses a single `&` in a conditional check. What does the single ampersand mean there?

```php
if( $some_array_or_other_var & SOME_CONSTANT_VARIABLE ){ 
    //do something here 
}
```

It does not look like a reference, that's what confuses me.

Comment: It is doing an [AND bitwise operation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is a bitwise AND operation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

If, after the bitwise AND, the result is "truthy", the clause will be satisfied.

For example:

```
3 & 2 == 2 // because, in base 2, 3 is 011 and 2 is 010
4 & 1 == 0 // because, in base 2, 4 is 100 and 1 is 001
```

This is commonly used to check a single bit in a bitset, by testing powers of two, you are actually checking if a specific bit is set.

Comment: @downvoter: what's wrong with the answer? Please let me know so that I can improve it!

Comment: Can you please add sample code to make everything clear

Comment: @ErdinçÇorbacı see my edit!

Comment: thanks maan ! up :)